# How to connect multiple Application ALB to single target group in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-alb

I have a particular requirement where I need to connect a single target group to multiple Application Load Balancer. It is possible in Elastic Load Balancer.

Below are the use cases:

1. ALB and ELB connecting to single Auto-scaling group
2. Multiple ALB connecting to single Auto-scaling group
3. Multiple ELB connecting to same Auto-scaling group (Possible)

Any pointers would help.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? What were the results?

Comment: not possible. one tg can be associated only with one LB. however you can attach one asg to multiple tgs.

Answer (score 0):

Connect Auto-scaling group to desired ALB target groups. This way same Auto-scaling group can be connected to multiple target groups.